# ExtJS: How to make a Window large enough to accommodate a FormPanel?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am creating a FormPanel with some fields and two buttons inside it, and hosting it inside a popup modal Window. The FormPanel has a default 'form' layout, the Window has 'fit'. The panel's optimal size is unknown to me beforehand. I would like to be able to programmatically resize the containing Window enough to fully display the FormPanel. I guess it all boils down to asking the layout manager what the optimal size of the panel is, but I haven't found any way to do that. I am using ExtJS 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

try resizing the window to fit the the height and width of form panel like

```
window.resizeTo(form.getWidth(),form.getHeight());
```